# Program Will Quit With an "else" Statment

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Python Script that will tell you what day you were born on based off of your DOB.

But I needed to make it so if you were born on either the months of "February","April","June","September","November" it would need to have a different equation, so for now I made it so if you put your date as "6" (June) it would just

```
print("This Is True")
```

So I arranged it like this

```
if M == '2':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

if M == '4':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

if M == '6':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

if M == '9':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

if M == '11':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

os.system('CLS')






if X == 'Answer':
    print('This Is True')
    input()

elif X != 'Answer':
    print('This is False')
    input()
```

yet when It is not one of the Months listed above it will

```
print('This is False')
```

yet when I enter something like "10" (October) the program will shut and not display "This is False"

I know I have asked a lot today but once again (if you couldn't tell by the code) I am VERY new

If anyone would also like to point out any tips on where the code could potentially be better here is all of it:

```
import os

M = 'Monday'
T = 'Tuesday'
W = 'Wednesday'
TT = 'Thursday'
F = 'Friday'
S = 'Saturday'
SS = 'Sunday'

print('Enter Your DOB as DD/MM/YYYY: ')

D = input("Day: ")




M = input("Month: ")



if M == '2':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

if M == '4':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

if M == '6':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

if M == '9':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

if M == '11':
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'




Y = input("Year: ")
if (len(Y)) < 4:
    print('You Have Entered A Too Short Or Too Long of a Year')
    input()
    os._exit(0)


os.system('CLS')






if X == 'Answer':
    print('This Is True')


elif X != 'Answer':
    print('This is False')
    input()




os.system('CLS')



print("You Were Born On A:")


input("Press ENTER To Exit")
```

Comment: You need to initialize X to a value before checking the month. Otherwise, if the value  of month is not one of those allowed, you get a `NameError: name 'X' is not defined`

Comment: You could learn how to debug code by yourself which means like isolating unexpected behavior. Making the example smaller and smaller is usually a good idea. Is the treatment of all the other months important for the treatment of October? Throw it out of the code and see if the behavior is still the same. Or go step by step through your code using a debugger.

Comment: Your code also does not seem complete, are you trying to predict what day the user is born based on his birth date in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` ?

Comment: @ DeveshKumarSingh yes the code is not complete yet and that is exactly what I am trying to do.

but i also need to take into account for leap years all the way up to the Users birth date. meaning I will need some hell of an equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this might be too advanced for you, but we have something called a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module which is meant for such things, so your code can be much shortened as

```
import os
import datetime

#Get date in correct format from user
dob = input('Enter Your DOB as DD/MM/YYYY:')

#Convert to datetime object
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')

#Get day of week
print("You Were Born On A {}".format(date_obj.strftime("%A")))
```

The output will look like

```
Enter Your DOB as DD/MM/YYYY:31/01/1991
You Were Born On A Thursday
```

In addition, some more ways you can improve your previous code.

1. Use a list to save all your `weekdays`
2. Instead of so many `if-else`, use a list like `['2' , '4', '6', '9', '11']` to save all your months, and use `in` to check if the month checks out, also if you are using `MM` you should check against `02,04,06...` etc
3. Use `sys.exit()` to exit your code

So an improvement on the code might look like.

```
import sys
import os

#List of weekdays
weekdays = ['Monday' ,'Tuesday' ,'Wednesday', 'Thursday' , 'Friday' ,'Saturday', 'Sunday']

print('Enter Your DOB as DD/MM/YYYY: ')

day = input("Day: ")
month = input("Month: ")

X = ''

#Check for month
if month in  ['02' , '04', '06', '09', '11']:
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

Y = input("Year: ")
if (len(Y)) < 4:
    print('You Have Entered A Too Short Or Too Long of a Year')
    sys.exit(0)

if X == 'Answer':
    print('This Is True')

elif X != 'Answer':
    print('This is False')

print("You Were Born On A:")

input("Press ENTER To Exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you aren't using True / False

I have rewritten something and added the idea from @Max

```
import os

M = 'Monday'
T = 'Tuesday'
W = 'Wednesday'
TT = 'Thursday'
F = 'Friday'
S = 'Saturday'
SS = 'Sunday'

X = False

print('Enter Your DOB as DD/MM/YYYY: ')

D = input("Day: ")
M = input("Month: ")

if M in ['2', '4', '6', '9', '11']:
    i = 30
    X = True

Y = input("Year: ")
if (len(Y)) < 4:
    print('You Have Entered A Too Short Or Too Long of a Year')
    input()
    os._exit(0)

os.system('CLS')

if X:
    print('This Is True')
else:
    print('This is False')
    input()

os.system('CLS')

print("You Were Born On A:")
input("Press ENTER To Exit")
```

Comment: This worked, but the first answer really made me understand what I was doing.
Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to some mistakes in your code:

- First you instantiate the `M` var to be `Monday` (`M = 'Monday'`), then you override it's value with an input from a user (`M = input("Month: ")`)
- You create the `X` var only when one of your `if` is set to `true`, meaning `M` is one of `2,4, 6, 9, 11)

You should create `X` outside the `if`

something like:

```
day = int(input("Day: "))
month = int(input("Month: "))

X = "Not Answer"
if M in (2, 4, 6, 9, 11):
    i = 30
    X = 'Answer'

...

if X == 'Answer':
    print('This Is True')
else:
    print('This is False')
    input()
```